# Json Foramatted data

Tags: php, json

I have below code

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT u.name, u.phone, m.email, m.mobile FROM user u, micards m WHERE m.usr_id=u.id ");

    while ( $row[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
}
    foreach(array_filter($row) as $key => $value) {
    $output[$value['phone']]['cards'][] = array(
    'email' => $value['email'],
    'mobile' => $value['mobile'],
    'name' => $value['name']
    );}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($output,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

getting output

```
{
    "919898989898": {
        "cards": [
            {
                "email": "vwxy@test.com",
                "mobile": "919898989898",
                "name": "abcd"
            },
            {
                "email": "pnqr@gmail.com",
                "mobile": "8686868686",
                "name": "abcd"
            }
        ]
    },
    "919923717198": {
        "cards": [
            {
                "email": "abcd@gmail.com",
                "mobile": "8686868686",
                "name": "defg"
            },
            {
                "email": "rstp@test.com",
                "mobile": "919898989898",
                "name": "defg"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But i want formatted output like

```
{
   "phone": ["919898989898": {
        "cards": [
            {
                "email": "vwxy@test.com",
                "mobile": "919898989898",
                "name": "abcd"
            },
            {
                "email": "pnqr@gmail.com",
                "mobile": "8686868686",
                "name": "abcd"
            }
        ]
    }],
    "phone": ["919923717198": {
        "cards": [
            {
                "email": "abcd@gmail.com",
                "mobile": "8686868686",
                "name": "defg"
            },
            {
                "email": "rstp@test.com",
                "mobile": "919898989898",
                "name": "defg"
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

Can anyone help me in this . I am new in json php.

Comment: Your expected output is invalid.

Comment: s check here http://jsonlint.com/ to check the output is valid json or not

Comment: loop each value in json data and format which format you want

Comment: may be my output is invalid. But i want in the same format like phone:"9198989898";{"cards":["....."]}

Comment: key `"phone"` is not unique in object, so this is impossible and your expected output is completely invalid.

Comment: you cannot have the same key twice in an object. moreover, the original format is perfect.

Comment: Please note that there's no such thing as *invalid JSON*. JSON is not like HTML, where you can provide any tag soup and the browser will do its best to fix it. If your output does not conform to the JSON spec then it isn't JSON at all. That implies that you can't use JSON tools to generate it automatically for you and the other end will not be able to use JSON parsers. Make sure you understand that before going on.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: I'm not satisfied with the phrasing. there *is* invalid JSON. just as there's invalid c++, python, or whatever code. HTML is the exception (which can be still invalid, but the browser tries to do it's "best"), and not JSON...

Comment: Is there *intentionally* invalid C++? ;-P

Comment: sure there is, I see it here on SO all the time ;P

Answer (score 0):

The format you want to use is invalid.

The object key `"phone"` is duplicated.

[RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)
2.2.  Objects - "The names within an object SHOULD be unique"

Comment: No issue. current json validate format is {
    "phone": [
        {
            "919923717198": {
                "cards": [
                    {
                        "email": "abcd@gmail.com",
                        "mobile": "8686868686",
                        "name": "defg"
                    },
                    {
                        "email": "rstp@test.com",
                        "mobile": "919898989898",
                        "name": "defg"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
} I want output same like this.

Comment: what you have in the question is invalid. PERIOD.